# REST-ful codeigniter disallow requests

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest

I'm start to learn REST-ful library in CodeIngiter

https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver

I do not understand, can I send post query from another host to rest-ful server? If this is possible, how can I prevent getting the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You prevent posting data or accessing data by using authentication. Phile Sturgeons REST-ful service provides 2 ways. By enabling username/password authentication and setting it to basic or digest. Or you can use private/public key authentication.

**EDIT**

Do you want to prevent any device accessing it your rest service or do you want to protect it? To protect it use:

```
$config['rest_auth'] = 'digest';
$config['rest_valid_logins'] = array('chooseUsername' => 'choosePassword');
```

To not let anybody access it:

```
$config['rest_ip_whitelist_enabled'] = true;
```

To control who can access it:

```
$config['rest_ip_whitelist'] = '74.365.72.97';
```

separate ips by comma if you have multiple ips. Although, most of devices are set to dynamic IP so when the IP changes, that device wont be able to connect to rest services. Not really a good way to go about unless you are the only person who wants to access the restful services.

Comment: If I set $config['rest_ip_whitelist_enabled']=false, then the queries will be run only from localhost?